# How do I (the designer) test and use an iPhone in development if I don't have access to computer in which the code is being written?

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi I'm intending to have an iPhone app developed by a coder from the US. I live in the UK. When the app is being developed, is there a way that I can preview and use the app as its being developed, so that I see if all the designs and functionality are correct?

Basically the app equivalent of seeing the developer URL of a website being developed.
-Thanks

Comment: Use Ad Hoc deployment. Your developer will know how to do this. If not, get a new developer. :)

Comment: Have a look at www.testflightapp.com

Answer (score 2):

You will need to give the developer the UDID of your device.  [You can find it via iTunes.](http://whatsmyudid.com/)

The developer will add your UDID to his developer profile.  Then he can create install files (the file extension is `.ipa`) that your device can use.  He sends you the IPA file and you use iTunes to install it.

Another approach is to use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/).  You can register your device with this site and with your developer's account on the site.  Then the developer can get your UDID from the web site and upload the .ipa file to the site.  Once he's done that, you can install the app directly from the web site without downloading it to a Mac or PC first.  Note that this is still reasonably secure because the app is encrypted and can only be run on the devices that are included in the developer's profile.

Comment: Another approach is a to use XCode's continuous integration if the developer has access to OSX Server.